# How to print the element of RowMatrix in java?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

```
RowMatrix mat = new RowMatrix(parsedData.rdd());
Matrix pc = mat.computePrincipalComponents(1);
RowMatrix projected = mat.multiply(pc);
```

I need to print the elements in the RowMatrix projected using java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`RowMatrix` is a distributed data structure and the only way to reliably output its content is to to fetch data to the driver and print locally. Typically it is an operation you want to avoid but general approach is as follows

```
val mat: RowMatrix = ???
mat
  .rows // Extract RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector]
  .collect // you can use toLocalIterator to limit memory usage
  .foreach(println) // Iterate over local Iterator and print
```

With Java equivalent being something like this:

```
List<Vector> vs = mat.rows().toJavaRDD().collect();
for(Vector v: vs) {
    System.out.println(v);
}
```

In practice there should be no need for operation like this. If your data is small enough to be handled locally there is no reason to use `DistributedMatrix`. If data is large but wide then `RowMatrix` is a poor choice for a distributed data structure.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to use it to debug my code in Scala with a small matrix. However, when running `val mat=RowMatrix=???` the `cala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing` error comes up. What am I missing?